# Sql - select by specific order

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a specific sql query.
For example we have a table named `people` and this table has this record:

```
- João (id ->1)
- Telmo (id ->2)
- Maria (id ->3)
- Henrique (id ->4)
- Pedro (id ->5)
```

I will obtain a specific person and for example i get `henrique id 4` the select has to show me this list:

```
- Henrique
- Maria
- Telmo
- João
- Pedro
```

And i also need to do inverse order

```
- Henrique
- Pedro
- João
- Telmo
- Maria
```

How can i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE WHEN` to check for the name:

```
select name
from mytable
order by case when name = 'Henrique' then 1 else 2 end, id;
```

And of course

```
select name
from mytable
order by case when name = 'Henrique' then 1 else 2 end, id desc;
```

for the reverse order with Henrique still first.

If you get the id instead of the name, then

```
order by case when id = 4 then 1 else 2 end, id [desc];
```

Comment: I'm not getting the correct listing. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: if i put id <= 4 works fine! Thank you @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Why `<= 4`? I thought that only ID **=** 4 was to be treated specially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` operator to get all the people with <= that id and all the people > id, e.g.:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id >= 4 ORDER BY id DESC

UNION 

SELECT name FROM table WHERE id > 4 ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
select `name` from `table_name` order by find_in_set(id,'4,3,2,1,5');
```

and to get the inverse list, use:

```
select `name` from `table_name` order by find_in_set(id,'4,5,1,2,3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the close `ORDER BY name` if you want a query who order your result by the decrement of your first letter in your name